# PHP MySQL how pass value of variables into email body using placeholders

Tags: php, mysql

I am building an emailing template system using PHP. The idea is that the same system can be used to send a variety of automated email, eg when people join a site etc. The contents of each email are held on a MySQL database and I use placeholders to represent dynamic elements such as name, email, etc. The placeholders take the form of two underscores before and after a name: `__name__`, (NB the stackoverflow markup may convert the underscores to make the placeholder name appear in bold here) and a separate field matches the placeholder to the variable it represents eg:

```
__name__=[($user['name'])], __email=[($user['email'])]
```

When I construct the email, the system takes the placeholders and holds them in an associative array:

```
$placeholders( '__name__' => $user['name'], '__email__' => $user['email'] );
```

This is exactly how the array appears. I have used explode to strip out the enclosing `[(` and `)]` brackets.

I am able to loop through the email content and use `Parsedown` and `preg_replace` to swap the placeholders with their corresponding variables, eg:

```
$body = 'Dear __name__, your email is __email__'
```

becomes:

```
$body = 'Dear $user['name'], your email is $user['email']
```

However, this is exactly how the content appears in the final email that is actually sent. The value of these variables (which I have successfully established previously in an array $user ) do not appear in the final text, eg:

```
'Dear John, your email is john@smith.com'.
```

**How do I get PHP to replace the variables with their values before the email is sent?**

PS I have also tried:

```
'Dear ' . $user['name'] . 'Your email is ' . $user['email']
```

(ie with an inverted comma and a period to differentiate the variables from the rest of the text ) but no avail. It appears as: 
Dear Mr Mercer,

Thank you for registering your details with mercermania.com.

Please verify your email address now

We now need to verify that the email address you supplied when you registered does indeed belong to you. Please click on the following link:

**http://www.mercermania.com/activation/?x=' . $user_info['email'] . '&y=' . $user_info['active'] . '**

I have done it before, so know it can be done but for the life of me I cannot remember how!

Any help greatly appreciated.

PS I am using PHP Mail::factory to send the email and an email is actually sent, and is received, so that is not the issue.

Comment: What do you get in email when you use the second approach?

Comment: Wow! that's a fast response! Thank you! exactly the same: $user['name'], $user['email']

Comment: The only way to interpolate a string that already exists (not a new string literal) is to use `eval`, which I recommend against. Instead consider using an existing templating engine like Twig (or many others) to convert your template to a string, and use a template like `Dear {{ name }}. Your email is {{ email }}.`

Comment: Pls put your full code block using the second approach. You must have done something wrong there.

Comment: The first approach should work if you use proper quotes: `$body = 'Dear $user['name'], your email is $user['email']` should be `$body = "Dear $user['name'], your email is $user['email']";`. If not, then the issue is elsewhere: show your whole code.